# Can this "headgear" be used for defense even if woven and curved sideways?

Tags: biology, creature-design, anatomy, self-defense, fight

I really like this concept for headgear and I was wondering about their use. Since I plan on designing a creature with similar headgear.
[image]

My theory is that due to the way they are bent they don't have the strongest structure and might be prone to fractures thus unusable in a fight, am I wrong?

Comment: they can't be horns with spades like that, not unless the bases is not horn only the spikes. antler maybe.  they are shaped more like something for specular display than defense, like many horns.

Comment: @John all I know is that antlers bleed and and have fur, but are they also supposed to be also more fragile?

Comment: they can be more fragile, but it mostly depends on their composition, it varies a lot, but they are still fairly tough, the real kicker is they shed and regrown each year.

Comment: A lot of people underestimate just how tough antler actually is.  For example, many Native Americans often used antlers as the tool of choice for napping... that is, they used antler to chip away at rocks that were themselves hard and tough enough to be used as knife blades, axe bits, and arrow heads.

Comment: @Nosajimiki they are certainly not made of butter but one must also point out that  sprinting into a headbutt isn't the same a napping hit with your hand while sitting.

Answer (score 3):

**Chicks dig them.**

Like other ostentatious displays of power to spare, the fact this guy can tote these things around mean he is super fit, finding food, not getting eaten by predators, free of parasites, and ready to sire all the young for the next generation.  The females of this species like a male with huge fancy horns and so such horns are selected for despite the fact that they are really heavy and get in his way.

The curly claws are products of this same female preference selective pressure.

Domesticated geldings do not develop the horns or claws and do better without them.  Except as regards mating which was taken off the table earlier in their lives.